# Javascript playing an endless loop audio file without delay

Tags: javascript, html, function, audio, wav

Title is pretty much self explanatory.

I want to create an endless loop with JavaScript but without stopping between reading (again) the same exact file.

Here is my code:

```
function playMySong(url)
{
    var audio=document.createElement('audio');
    audio.style.display="none";
    audio.src=url;
    audio.autoplay=true;
    audio.onended=function()
    {
        playMySong('whiteNoise.wav');
    };
    document.body.appendChild(audio);
}

playMySong('whiteNoise.wav');
```

My code works (almost) perfectly but I want to get read of the tiny delay between the end of the sound to the beginning of the same exact file.

not it's:

```
[whiteNoise.wav][0.2ms delay][whiteNoise.wav]
```

I want:

```
[whiteNoise.wav][whiteNoise.wav]
```

:)

Comment: What about using the `loop` attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are loading the audio file again and again when it reaches the end. Obviously, loading resources will take time.

Why don't you use a simple [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#attr-loop) attribute to the `audio` element? It will loop the audio clip itself without loading the resource again and again.

```js
function playMySong(url)
{
    var audio=document.createElement('audio');
    audio.style.display="none";
    audio.src=url;
    audio.autoplay=true;
    audio.loop = true;
    document.body.appendChild(audio);
}

playMySong('whiteNoise.wav');
```